# ConfigModule doesn't work in forRootAsync. Nest.js

Tags: nestjs

So, i want to understand why i need to add forRoot() in the first line?

[with forRoot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db7MN.png)

because if I don't add this text, the configService.get('...') function will return undefined in the getKnexConfig function

[getKnexConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqeqo.png)

Comment: what if you do the same `.get()` call but for the module that has imported the `ConfigModule.forRoot()` module? just to make sure that that env value do exists. Inject the `ConfigService` provider into that module and try it out

Comment: @MicaelLevi the env value exists because it works fine with forRoot(). the main question is: why should I add forRoot() to the imports above if I add ConfigModule to the imports inside forRootAsync? how it works? and why doesn't it work without forRoot()?